# Dedicated li-ion step up drivers

Tags: lithium-ion, battery-operated, lithium, buck-boost, step-up

I have a design which will include the optional use case of boosting up to 7V from a li-ion battery.
I can't seem to find any drivers dedicated to li-ion for this? There seem to be a few buck boost that can generate 3V3. Should I use that 3V3 and boost using a standard boost converter? The Li-ion battery is also going straight into an IC which includes li-ion charge and protection circuitry.

I know this is wasteful use of the battery but will only be used if the user sets the jumper in that position as an additional (but limited) design feature.

Comment: Just use a boost converter to take the battery voltage and output 7 volts.

Comment: Why not use 2 batteries in series ? The nominal Li-ion voltage is 3.7, that will make you 7.4 without anything else. At full charge, you get 8.4, at low charge you get 6.6V. Should be fine for most applications.